# Is it possible to mimic the 'ecto.load' task using Ecto.Migrator for an Elixir Release?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I’m deploying with Releases for the first time and I’ve run into the issue where I need to create my database and populate it with some seed files before launching the web servers. The guide here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html indicates that this can be done using the low level Ecto.Migrator api described here https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migrator.html#run/.

My current project uses a structure.sql file and discards old migration files as they became numerous and backtracked a lot during the project. In my dev environment I had a mix task like this:

```
  "ecto.setup": [
    "ecto.create",
    "ecto.load",
    "ecto.migrate",
    "run priv/repo/seeds.exs",
    "run priv/repo/more_seeds.exs"
  ],
```

that created the database structure and populated it with key seed files. I’m struggling to see how that would be possible using the API linked in the guides though as they discuss exclusively traversing a bunch of migration files.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the only reasonable way would be to include `mix` application to the release _and_ run mix tasks directly as `Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Create.run()` etc.

Comment: looks it was a design mistake to rely so much on mix tasks.